# Laravel 8 - How to store a form's data inside a collection?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, controller

I am a beginner in the Laravel framework, and I am having some trouble trying to store the data that was inserted in a form into a Collection.

This is the form where you get the data

```
<form action="{{ url('/add_client') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Add Client" name="client" required></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="+"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is where the data is outputed

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Added Clients</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <div class="border border-dark" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;">
        @isset($clients)
            @foreach ($clients as $client)
                <div class="bg-info" style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px;">{{ $client }}</div>
            @endforeach
        @endisset
    </div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

This is where a new collection is added, inserting the data that was read from the form, and go back to the view '/client' which is the page where the data gets read and will be outputed

```
public function addClient (Request $req, Collection $clients) {

    $clients->push($req->input('client'));

    return view('client')->with('clients', $clients);
}
```

This is the routing page (The fetchData function is unrelated)

```
Route::get('/client', [ClientController::class, 'fetchData']);
Route::post('/add_client', [ClientController::class, 'addClient']);
```

I would like that the $clients variable created a new "entry" for each time that data was submitted, and I would like to be able to continue to access the data that was submitted before and inserted into the collection. I don't want to store it into a database.

Comment: every request to the application the entire application is completely reloaded (how php works) ... there is no persistence between processes, you would have to persist the data some where (like a database, a file, some type of persistent cache, etc etc)

Comment: @BrianThompson I do not need $clients to be a collection necessarily. But I want to store the input data inside an array type of variable. I need to present every thing that is submitted. It is kinda of similar to how a tag system would work, with you adding the tags and they appearing immediatly, and every time you add a new one, the old one(s) don't disappear.